# prevent schema change permissions to user

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a user (d2user) the roles of this user is only read and write.. so we added role `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` using `sp_addrolemember` sys proc.

However when I login with this user.. I am able to change the tables schemas that this user owned.

this is working perfectly where it should not work.

```
 ALTER SCHEMA guest TRANSFER dbo.TestData;
 GO
```

I tried to restrict it using :

```
 REVOKE Alter any schema ON ROLE::db_datareader FROM d2user CASCADE;
```

However no luck I am getting incorrect syntax error, this user is still able to alter schema.. can somebody help plss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user has ALTER permissions because they have one of

- db_ddl_admin
- db_owner
- sysadmin

You can revoke ddl_admin but the other 2 will *always* have rights to change things

You can check role permissions with these

```
EXEC sp_helprolemember; -- uses sys.database_role_members if you prefer to query this
EXEC sp_helpsrvrolemember;
```

Comment: User does have sysadmin but not other two. If I uncheck sysadmin I cannot even see the database objects.. the node doesnt explore.

Comment: With sysadmin, they have full control of SQL Server. If you remove this, they have permissions to see only what you grant them using GRANT VIEW DEFINITION in the database

Comment: i removed sysadmin. executed - GRANT ANY VIEW DEFINITION To Publilc - still I cannot see the objects

Comment: When I remove sysadmin, the database went completely inaccessible. I cannot even query the tables